# WebSocket Client not connecting to server(implemented in netty)

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I followed the code exactly(netty-in-action) and from the client side(interface included in the code of chapter 11) i wasn't able to connect to the netty chatserver.
the url i entered was ws://localhost:9099 in the client browser interface and it couldn't connect

the server code is taken from 
https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/tree/master/src/main/java/com/manning/nettyinaction/chapter11

and the client interface is taken from
https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/tree/master/src/main/resources